# Python realization of Matlab 'Outer product'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab

I am trying to rewrite the following snippet of Matlab code about outer product of matrices into python code,

```
function Y = matlab_outer_product(X,x)
A = reshape(X, [size(X) ones(1,ndims(x))]);
B = reshape(x, [ones(1,ndims(X)) size(x)]);
Y = squeeze(bsxfun(@times,A,B));
end
```

My one-to-one translation of this to python code is as following (considering how the shape of numpy array and matlab matrices are arranged),

```
def python_outer_product(X, x):
    X_shape = list(X.shape)
    x_shape = list(x.shape)
    A = X.reshape(*list(np.ones(np.ndim(x),dtype=int)),*X_shape)
    B = x.reshape(*x_shape,*list(np.ones(np.ndim(X),dtype=int)))
    Y = A*B
    return Y.squeeze()
```

Then trying the inputs, for instance,

```
matlab_outer_product([1,2],[[3,4];[5,6]])
python_out_product(np.array([[1,2]], np.array([[3,4],[5,6]])))
```

The outputs don't quite match. In matlab, it outputs

```
output(:,:,1) = [[3,5];[6,10]]
output(:,:,2) = [[4,6];[8,12]]
```

In python, it outputs

```
output = array([
       [[ 3,  6],
        [ 4,  8]],

       [[ 5, 10],
        [ 6, 12]]
])
```

They're almost identical, but not quite. I wonder what's wrong with code and how to change the python code to match with matlab output?

Comment: MATLAB uses F-order, where the trailing dimension is outermost.  `numpy` uses C-order (by default) with the leading dimension outermost.  Note that the MATLAB display "iterates" on the trailing dimension.  `numpy` divides the leading dimension in to blocks.  Focus on getting the right values, but don't try to force the `numpy` layout to match.  It's not worth the effort.

Comment: in the matlab code you are reshaping A to start with `X` dimensions and then ones and in the python code it is reversed, try reshaping both the same way and see if that gives you what you are expecting

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, no this would not give me the answer. Because for instance in matlab a (2,2,3,1) array is equivalent to to a numpy (3,1,2,2) array. This is the reason why I write in this particular way in python code above.

Comment: @hpaulj I see! But what I am trying to accomplish is about rewriting a giant matlab program into python. And the rest of the program depending such function. I need to make them exactly the same. Otherwise, more effort might be devoted later :-(

Comment: ok, but if that is the case how is the output wrong? you say it is nearly identical but not quite, what are you expecting if you already know the dimensions are going to be flipped because that is the only difference I am seeing.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I need them exactly the same. You're right that in this case only one dimension is somehow flipped, but later I will use this function to calculate higher order matrices, more dimensions will be flipped. It would soon be impractical to do, for instance, ```swapaxes``` every time it outputs an matrix.

Comment: ok so either you stop relying on `squeeze` so that which dimension gets collapsed is consistent or you just don't treat the dimensions differently in numpy, I am not getting what you are expecting.  if you would end up with a (3,1,4,5) matrix then squeeze goes to (3,4,5) or if it was in the other order (4,5,3,1) it gets squeezed to (4,5,3) so it is hard to keep track of which dimension means what, again what are you expecting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236740/discussion-between-tadhg-mcdonald-jensen-and-coolgas).

Comment: I highly recommend that you use arrays with all different sizes, so that you can keep track of those. Making everything have a size of 2 is very confusing, and doesn't allow you to find mismatches in dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

In full gory detail (since my MATLAB memory is old):

### Octave

```
>> X = [1,2];
>> x = [[3,4];[5,6]];
>> A = reshape(X, [size(X) ones(1,ndims(x))]);
>> B = reshape(x, [ones(1,ndims(X)) size(x)]);
>> A
A =

   1   2

>> B
B =

ans(:,:,1,1) =  3
ans(:,:,2,1) =  5
ans(:,:,1,2) =  4
ans(:,:,2,2) =  6

>> bsxfun(@times,A,B)
ans =

ans(:,:,1,1) =

   3   6

ans(:,:,2,1) =

    5   10

ans(:,:,1,2) =

   4   8

ans(:,:,2,2) =

    6   12

>> squeeze(bsxfun(@times,A,B))
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =

    3    5
    6   10

ans(:,:,2) =

    4    6
    8   12
```

You start with a (1,2) and (2,2), expand the second to (1,1,2,2).  The `bsxfun` produces a (1,2,2,2) which is squeezed to (2,2,2).

`A` is `X` reshaped to `[1   2   1   1]`, but the two outer size 1 dimensions are squeeze out, resulting in no change.

This MATLAB outter is a bit convoluted, using `bsxfun` to perform elementwise multiplication of (1,2,1,1) with (1,1,1,2).  At least in Octave it's the same as

```
A.*B
```

### In numpy

```
In [77]: X
Out[77]: array([[1, 2]])    # (1,2)
In [78]: x
Out[78]: 
array([[3, 4],              # (2,2)
       [5, 6]])
```

Note that the MATLAB/Octave `x` when flattened has elements (3,5,4,6), while the numpy ravel is [3,4,5,6].

In numpy I can simply do:

```
In [79]: X[:,:,None,None]*x
Out[79]: 
array([[[[ 3,  4],          (1,2,2,2)
         [ 5,  6]],

        [[ 6,  8],
         [10, 12]]]])
```

or without the extra size 1 dimension of `X`:

```
In [84]: (X[0,:,None,None]*x)
Out[84]: 
array([[[ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6]],

       [[ 6,  8],
        [10, 12]]])

In [85]: (X[0,:,None,None]*x).ravel()
Out[85]: array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  6,  8, 10, 12])
```

compare that with the Octave ravel

```
>> squeeze(bsxfun(@times,A,B))(:)'
ans =

    3    6    5   10    4    8    6   12
```

We could add a transpose to the numpy

```
In [96]: (X[0,:,None,None]*x).transpose(2,1,0).ravel()
Out[96]: array([ 3,  6,  5, 10,  4,  8,  6, 12])
In [97]: (X[0,:,None,None]*x).transpose(2,1,0)
Out[97]: 
array([[[ 3,  6],
        [ 5, 10]],

       [[ 4,  8],
        [ 6, 12]]])
```

At least in numpy we can tweak the dimension order in lots of ways, so I won't try to suggest an optimal.  I still think it's better to write code that's "natural" to numpy than to slavishly match the MATLAB order.

### another try

I realized, above, that the MATLAB is just doing `A*.B` with
(1,2,1,1) arrays (1,1,1,2), where the extra 1's were added to "broadcast".

Using transpose to the same dimension outermost (leading in numpy)

```
In [5]: X = X.T; x = x.T
In [6]: X.shape
Out[6]: (2, 1)
In [7]: x.shape
Out[7]: (2, 2)
In [8]: x
Out[8]: 
array([[3, 5],
       [4, 6]])
In [9]: x.ravel()
Out[9]: array([3, 5, 4, 6])   # compare with MATLAB (:)'
```

Elementwise multiplication with the same dimension expansion:

```
In [10]: X[None,None,:,:]*x[:,:,None,None]
Out[10]: 
array([[[[ 3],
         [ 6]],

        [[ 5],
         [10]]],


       [[[ 4],
         [ 8]],

        [[ 6],
         [12]]]])
In [11]: _.shape
Out[11]: (2, 2, 2, 1)         # compare with octave (1,2,2,2)
In [12]: __.squeeze()
Out[12]: 
array([[[ 3,  6],
        [ 5, 10]],

       [[ 4,  8],
        [ 6, 12]]])
```

the ravel is the same as Octave:

```
In [13]: ___.ravel()
Out[13]: array([ 3,  6,  5, 10,  4,  8,  6, 12])
```

`expand_dims` can be used instead of the indexing.  Internally it uses `reshape`:

```
In [15]: np.expand_dims(X,(0,1)).shape
Out[15]: (1, 1, 2, 1)
In [16]: np.expand_dims(x,(2,3)).shape
Out[16]: (2, 2, 1, 1)
```

Comment: while `X[:,:,None,None]` feels like a more natural way of doing this, I do want to point out that if the initial matrices were higher than 2D then it would not shape the output correctly where as the way it is reshaped in the OP would still correctly compute an outer product.  you could do `idx = (*itertools.repeat(slice(None), len(X.shape)), *itertools.repeat(None, len(x.shape))) ; X[idx] * x` to make it work in general but that feels even more overkill.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You are absolutely correct on the point that if the initial matrices where higher than 2D, the python code will magically give me correct answer.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen can you elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: @hpaulj. Thx for your answer! It rocks! But this method is not generalizable, my experience on this question is to avoid any transpose, axeswap on this challenge.

Comment: `X[:,:,None,None]` reshapes a `(m by n)` matrix to shape `(m,n,1,1)` matrix which when multiplied by a `(j by k)` matrix gives shape `(m,n,j,k)` (which is very different from matlab behaviour) if the matrix is shape `(m,n,a)` it reshapes to size `(m,n,1,1,a)` which will will cause problems when you multiply by `(j by k)`, the code with `repeat(slice(None))` does the equivalent right number of slicing for any number of dimensions

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, I realized that the MATLAB is just `A.*B`; my focus was on understanding the MATLAB and how the 'C' numpy order creates differences in dimensions and layout.  Since the OP wasn't starting out with the same arrays, I wasn't aiming for the most general equivalent.

Comment: I wasn't trying to criticize your answer, you do a far more thorough job than I could! to me the 3D case seemed like a potential gap that someone may want a more generic solution for in which case I have the start to some technique in my comment.  I honestly learned a lot more about slicing and how they differ in both languages from this answer so thanks again!